# How to create a loop in a cell array and reshape matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, reshape, cell-array

I have the following script to calculate fluid perturbations. 
I am reading in 2D velocity fields and then storing this data in a cell array. 
In the present example i have only 4 velocity fields from different time steps, but eventually I will have around 300+

The velocity fields are stored in the cell array and that part works. What i need help with is to create a loop to then reshape the matrices in the cell array and store as a separate matrix.

So far i have

```
%% Calculating the Perturbation
% The perturbation is calculated by subtracting the average velocity form
% the instantaneous. 
% Below are the instantaneous velocity fields in each direction

% u velocity
U = num2cell(u,1);

% v velocity
V = num2cell(v,1);

% w velocity
W = num2cell(w,1);
```

From here i now want to reshape the matrix in the cell arrays and save as follows:

```
%% Reshape the velocity vectors into matrices



u1d = reshape(cell2mat(U(1,1)),[nx ny]);
u2d = reshape(cell2mat(U(1,2)),[nx ny]);
u3d = reshape(cell2mat(U(1,3)),[nx ny]);
u4d = reshape(cell2mat(U(1,4)),[nx ny]);

v1d = reshape(cell2mat(V(1,1)),[nx ny]);
v2d = reshape(cell2mat(V(1,2)),[nx ny]);
v3d = reshape(cell2mat(V(1,3)),[nx ny]);
v4d = reshape(cell2mat(V(1,4)),[nx ny]);

w1d = reshape(cell2mat(W(1,1)),[nx ny]);
w2d = reshape(cell2mat(W(1,2)),[nx ny]);
w3d = reshape(cell2mat(W(1,3)),[nx ny]);
w4d = reshape(cell2mat(W(1,4)),[nx ny]);
```

now this method is very long and i am not sure how to create a loop to reshape the matrix and then rename them as shown above. Individually will take too long and i want to process 300+ files. I would definitely appreciate help with this. I have done it manually as thats were my knowledge goes to.

The reason i want it as `u1d, u2d...v1d, v2d .... w1d...` is to calculate the two point correlation. So once i get `u1d....`etc i will subtract it from the average velocity field. Which is another part of the code. I need help to create a loop for this section.

Comment: What are the dimensions of `u`, `v`, and `w`? Also I see you put these values into a cell array and then take them back out of a cell array in `u1d`, ... Can you explain why you are doing that?

Comment: The dimensions of u, v and w are 524288x4 respectively. The reason i put them in a cell array and then take them back out is to make the code more efficient and not have too many variables. At first i had the following `% u velocity
u1 = u(:,1);
u2 = u(:,2);
u3 = u(:,3);
u4 = u(:,4);`. Now this method was too long as i would have had to create u1....u300 hence i put them into a cell array which then makes the code into a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some pointers:

- `cell2mat(U(1,1))` is the same as `U{1,1}`. You should prefer the latter, it's much more efficient because it doesn't do a function call.
- Naming variables `u1d`, `u2d`, `u3d`, ... is usually a bad idea. You already figured you could use a cell array `U` to store your vectors, you should store  these also in a cell array: `ud{1}`, `ud{2}`, `ud{3}`, ...

Given these two points, you can do your thing using a loop:

```
for ii=1:4
   ud{ii} = reshape(U{ii},[nx ny]);
end
```

However, using a cell array in this case is actually not even necessary, it is just as much work to do indexing like this: `U{1,1}` as like this: `u(:,1)`. You should prefer the latter, as that is how your data comes in: you avoid the copy needed to generate the cell array.

Given you numeric array `u` of size `n`x`k`, with `k` vectors (`k=4` in your example), and `n==nx*ny` the number of elements in each, you can do:

```
ud = reshape(u, nx, ny, k);
```

which is the same as

```
ud = reshape(u, nx, ny, []);
```

In this last version MATLAB figures out what `k` should be given the size of `u`.

From here on, you index `ud(:,:,1)` to get your `u1d`, etc.

Do note that `reshape` does not copy data. `ud` will reference the same data as `u` until you change one of the two arrays. As soon as you try to change data in one of them, a copy of the full array will be made. This is called "lazy copying". If you don't need to preserve `u`, I recommend that you don't create a new variable, simply do `u = reshape(u...)`. This will prevent the data from being copied.

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly what i needed. The answer is explained excellently.